# Как скомпилировать .g4 в .cs | Что необходимо настроить для работы с Antlr в VS2019

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio-2019, antlr

Пятый день сижу, потаюсь разобраться, все документации до дыр перечитал, хотя возможно где-то что-то не так понял... Что необходимо сделать для работы c Antlr в Visual Studio 2019? По большинству инструкций, достаточно установить Antlr4.Runtime. Ну ок, что дальше? Если только через консоль можно компилировать, то что, где и как? Или что делать с файлом "antlr-4.8-complete.jar" после его скачивания с офф. сайта (если это вообще нужно)?

1. Что нужно установить для работы с Antlr4 в Visual Stupio 2019?
2. Как потом компилировать .g4 в .cs?

Comment: Минус не мой, но проголосовал за закрытие как "мало подробностей". Если же хотите распутаться... Попробуйте разбить свою большую непонятную задачу "Как изучить antlk" на серию маленьких, конкретных, выписать все, посмотреть какие знаете, какие надо копать, по каждой поискать уроки в сети, потренироваться... И после каждой задачи ищите "какой следующий шаг попробовать".

Comment: `Попробуйте разбить свою большую непонятную задачу "Как изучить antlk" на серию маленьких` - спасибо, но я и разбил. И я уже начитался и насмотрелся. Теперь, как раз, время для шага `потренироваться`, как вы говорите. И тут у меня загвоздка со средой, в которой я планирую "потренироваться".

Comment: И что не попалось ни одного видео, где бы хелловорд бы компилировался? о_О

Comment: Так, чтобы от начала до конца - нет. Есть одно видео, но там компилируется в java, без vs, плюс старая версия. Да и к тому же я пробовал точь в точь делать, ошибки вылетали... Все остальные видео (кстати не много, на русском вообще нет) только про матчасть.

Answer (score 3):

Устанавливать нужно не в `Visual Studio`, а в нужный проект. Насколько я понял вам нужен нугет пакет `Antlr4.Runtime.Standard`.

[image: как устанавливать нугет пакет]

после установки пакета добавьте в код

```
using Antlr4.Runtime;
using Antlr4.Runtime.Tree;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Только как после этого компилировать .g4 файлы в .cs?

Comment: Сорян, я не работал с этим пакетом.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lc9JlXyBG4E&t=394s

Comment: Я это видео 4 раза уже пересматривал ^^. Хотя не исключаю, что мог что-то пропустить: https://prnt.sc/vkte08

Comment: Если пробовать что-то вроде `grun addition equation -gui 4+5`, получаю: `Can't load addition as lexer or parser`.